# I don't understand how to find the derivative when it shows in this form??

Tags: derivatives

$$ \left (\frac  {d^{a-1}}{dz^{a-1}}  z^a +a^2\right) $$

I understand that this is a derivative with respect to z , and that if instead of  $( {a-1}) $ this was 2 it would be the second derivative. But i have no idea what to do with the a-1 , any help would be much appreciated!

-- Both z and a are complex variables

Comment: I am not sure what it is supposed to mean if $a$ is not an integer.  However there is a generalization called q derivative.  This may help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative#Higher-order_derivatives_and_differential_operators

Answer (score 1):

See that if $a=3$, you have the 2nd derivative of $z^3$ which is $3\cdot 2z = 3!z$

If $a=4$, you have the 3rd derivative of $z^4$, which is $4\cdot 3\cdot 2z=4!z$

So a pattern emerges.

I'm assuming $a$ has to be a positive integer.  (If not, then we're talking fractional derivatives and that's a HUGE can of worms.)

Comment: Yes , a > 0. Is  there any way to use a general form if i don't know the value of a? @B.Goddard

Comment: @VictorOrta: Yes, you should follow the pattern that B. Goddard has hinted at in his answer.  It provides an answer for general $a$.

Comment: @VictorOrta  That $a$ is an integer is the important thing.  (Unless you want to take the $\pi$th derivative of something...?)